# This plant doesn’t want to stay alive

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, plant-care

I have searched everywhere. It was given to me by a friend who kept almost killing it. Consequently, I keep almost killing it too because I can’t figure out what it is or how to care for it. There used to be a lot more of it, and it’s always on the edge of death, yet miraculously hasn’t fully died. At this point, I’m determined to keep the stupid thing alive - it’s mocking me and I must win. Does anyone know what it is?
[image]

Comment: I keep one in my bathroom with a peace lily and water every 3 or 4 days. If u want to nurse sick plants u might want to set up a propagation box. Great way to keep mosses also. Moss at the bottom (on gravel then charcoal then dry moss soil mix), sick plants getting well again for a few days on top. Great way to root cuttings and grow seeds also. Never overwater plants. Much easier too kill by over watering then under watering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Fittonia, common name Nerve plant. These can be difficult to keep healthy because  they require high humidity, draught free conditions and steady, warm temperatures. They do not appreciate sunlight either, preferring  bright daylight instead - think rain forest conditions. They're good in terrariums, but keeping the humidity up in an ordinary room can be difficult. More info here https://www.thespruce.com/grow-fittonia-houseplants-indoors-1902486

Comment: Radical. This is the answer I needed!  I'll see what I can do to make sure it stays alive now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Cut back on the watering, too.  Allow the soil to dry out a bit in between waterings.  Make a temporary 'green house' or terrarium using sticks and saran wrap?  Never to be put in direct sun.  Air your plant by opening up the saran wrap.  Plants need CO2 and when they transpire O2 it sort of suffocates when in an enclosed environment because the plants use up CO2 to do photosynthesis and give off O2. The air needs moved, by a fan so that the CO2 in the fresh air replaces the old air and can get near the leaf skins.  Don't water every single day.  Especially if you enclose the environment!

Comment: This plant needs draught free conditions, but you should use a fan to move the air?