# What is the name of this plant, please, and how do I propagate it ? (pic)

Tags: identification, propagation

I have nursed this (indoor) fragile plant through thick and thin and now it is flourishing but desperately needs re-potting. Before I risk upsetting it, I want to propagate it but have thus far failed miserably, attempting to take a cutting and planting the cut end straight into soil.

Can anyone tell me its name and how to propagate it ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a nerve plant, or Fittonia! I asked a [similar question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/43414/this-plant-doesn-t-want-to-stay-alive) in this SE recently. They're super, super fiddly plants, but it helped me a lot knowing what it was. (I didn't keep my plant in a warm or humid enough environment.) [THIS](https://www.thespruce.com/grow-fittonia-houseplants-indoors-1902486) site has some great information on caring for and propegating a nerve plant. For propagation, this site recommends taking some leaf cuttings with 2 or more growing nodes on it, and replanting the cutting in a peat based soil. It should sprout within 2-3 weeks.

Comment: Many, many thanks for the information.