# My Fittonia Hybrid plant looks dead but I really hope it’s not

Tags: houseplants

[image]

I have moved it to a less light place and watered it every day but it’s still like this. I was really hoping someone could help revive it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late to save it - whilst Fittonia does not like to suffer drought, it also does not appreciate having wet soil round its roots all the time. They like high humidity, but that refers to the air around the plant, not the roots. Using a pebble tray can help with humidity - that involves using a tray that is wider than the pot, placing pebbles inside and keeping the tray half topped up with water, with the plant stood in the centre of the tray, on top of the pebbles but not in contact with the water.

Watering every day while its in this state is not appropriate; there are general rules for watering houseplants, which are that you only water when the surface of the soil in the pot feels just about dry to the touch, water thoroughly and allow the excess to drain away freely from the holes in the base of the pot. Any outer pot or tray should be emptied after 30 minutes so the plant is not left sitting in water.

I can only suggest you follow the watering routine mentioned here, keep the plant somewhere relatively humid and reasonably bright, but out of sun, remove any withered or shrivelled growth, mist the plant occasionally, and wait and see what happens. Further info on how to care for these plants here https://www.thespruce.com/grow-fittonia-houseplants-indoors-1902486

Answer (score 0):

Fittonia needs high humidity and indirect light. See this previous highly rated [question and answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/43414/this-plant-doesn-t-want-to-stay-alive). There are many other discussions related to Fittonia/nerve plant.

Immediate action might be to remove the label, ensure the soil is moist but not wet, put the whole thing in a large clear plastic bag to raise the humidity, keep toasty warm and provide indirect light, leave it alone for several weeks and hope for the best.